# Android библиотека TextDrawable не отрисовывает элемент при Transition

Tags: android, transition

Всем доброго времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста такую вещь. Есть список RecyclerView в элементе списка есть рисунок в виде круга с первой буквой заголовка элемента списка, для отрисовки кружка использую библиотеку TextDrawable https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable.
Круг отрисовываю так

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NoteViewHolder holder, int i) {
        final NoteClass selectedNote = data.get(i);
        holder.tvNoteTittle.setText(data.get(i).getTittle());
        holder.tvNoteCreate.setText("Дата создания: " + data.get(i).getStringDateCreate());
        holder.tvNoteUpdate.setText("Дата обновления: " + data.get(i).getStringDateUpdate());
        holder.itemView.setActivated(selectedItems.get(i, false));
        TextDrawable drawable2 = TextDrawable.builder()
                .buildRound("A", Color.RED);
        holder.ivIconNote.setImageDrawable(drawable2);
    }
```

При клике на элемент открывается активити с деталкой, где я также хочу отрисовать такой же круг с такой же буквой, только побольше.

### Код вызова деталки MainActivity

```
private void elementView(NoteClass _note){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoteActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(NoteActivity.KEY_NOTE, _note);
    intent.putExtra(NoteActivity.KEY_CODE, requestCodeView);
    ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.
            makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, selectImage, getString(R.string.activity_image_trans));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCodeView, options.toBundle());
    }
    else
        startActivityForResult(intent, requestCodeView);
}
```

### Код активити деталки NoteActivity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);
    if(getIntent().hasExtra(KEY_NOTE))
        note = (NoteClass)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(KEY_NOTE);
    requestCode = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_CODE, 0);
    initViews();
    initData();
    setClickListener();
}

private void initViews(){
    etTittle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_tittle_note);
    etText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_text_note);
    btnSave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save_note);
    btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel_note);
    btnOk = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_ok_note);
    imAvatar = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_avatar);
    TextDrawable drawable2 = TextDrawable.builder()
            .buildRound("A", Color.RED);
    imAvatar.setImageDrawable(drawable2);
}
```

Я хочу чтобы переход между активити происходил с помощью transition Shared elements in Activities. 
Проставляю в лайаутах следующее

### maket_rv_note.xml

```
<ImageView android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/iv_icon_note"
       android:transitionName="@string/activity_image_trans" />
```

### activity_note.xml

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_avatar"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:transitionName="@string/activity_image_trans"/>
```

При нажатии видно что произошёл анимированный переход, но на деталке(NoteActivity) вместо рисунка пустота! Дебажил, проходит без ошибок и всё присваивает, в логи никаких видимых ошибок не выдаёт. Если рисунок присвоить в xml заранее то пройдёт как надо и рисунок будет на месте отрисованный. Если убрать все Transitions то при открытии деталки(NoteActivity) круг отрисовываеться как надо. Но мне то надо отрисовывать динамически, и присваивание рисунка заранее мне не подходит. Подскажите кто сталкивался с таким? И что можете посоветовать. Очень сильно поможете, если подскажите что делать и что я делаю не так? P.S. только начал осваивать transitions так что могу где-то ошибаться. Всем заранее огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Промучался с этим пару часов: как оказалось, для транзишенов нужно выставлять явную высоту и ширину (в обоих местах):

```
TextDrawable.builder()
.height(40) //pixels
.width(40) //pixels
.buildRound("A", Color.RED);
```